# L'influence de la sémantique du « clip » sur la familiarité de la juxtaposition de « choc » avec « vidéo » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, noms, trait-d-union

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/arts/musique/201902/10/01-5214223-grammy-awards-lady-gaga-childish-gambino-et-drake-recompenses.php) sur la soirée des *Grammy Awards*, je lis ce qui suit au sujet d'un [artiste](https://www.grammy.com/grammys/artists/childish-gambino) et de son œuvre :

> Sa **vidéo choc** dénonçant le règne des armes à feu et du racisme aux
>   États-Unis, [vue par des dizaines [NDLR des centaines] de millions de
>   personnes sur l'internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYOjWnS4cMY), a aussi reçu le prix du «meilleur **clip**».
>   (La Presse, je souligne et ajoute la note sur le nombre de visionnements)

On a juxtaposé le nom [*choc*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choc) (*pour signifier que la réalité à laquelle se réfère cet autre nom provoque une grande émotion ou suscite un vif intérêt*, BDL) à *vidéo* mais sans trait d'union. Je lis en ce qui a trait à [cet emploi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=choc&id=3586) de *choc* que « plus une forme devient courante, plus les gens ont tendance à l'orthographier avec un trait d’union » (BDL). D'autre part on définit le [*(vidéo)clip*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365017) comme étant un « film vidéo, bref et **percutant** qui utilise nombre d'effets spéciaux, réalisé pour illustrer une chanson » (GDT, je souligne).

- Peut-on expliquer si on pense ou non que la sémantique du *clip*,
  dont les emplois rencontrent ceux de la *vidéo*, ou autre chose,
  empêche généralement « vidéo choc » de devenir plus courant
  (*vidéo-choc*) ou de se « lexicaliser » ?

Answer (score 1):

L'autre aspect qu'il faudrait, à mon avis, pour que l'expression se lexicalise avec un trait d'union, c'est une spécificité du sens du nom *choc* lorsqu'il est associé à *vidéo*.

Or en l'essence il n'y en a pas : on dit *une vidéo choc* aussi bien que *un article choc*, *un rapport choc*, *un album choc* ou *un spectacle choc*. Le nom *choc* est employé avec une valeur adjectivale relativement portable d'un type de production intellectuelle à un autre.

De même on ne commencerait pas à écrire ciel-bleu simplement parce que le ciel est souvent affublé de cet adjectif.

Par contraste, le sens de *clip* dans *vidéo-clip* est très spécifique à la vidéo, et se rapporte à sa courte durée. L'expression forme une unité sémantique indivisible, ce qui rend peut-être sa lexicalisation plus probable.